# application: didReceiveLocalNotification Runs Every Launch After 1st Local Notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am working on an application that uses iOS's UILocalNotifications to alert the user that action needs to be completed on their part. I am able to create my notifications and have them fire properly. However, when returning to the app I am having an issue. After the first time a notification fired my 'application: didRecieveLocalNotification' runs every time, with the 1st notifications data. I can log out all the notifications in the queue, and even if the queue is empty it will still run the notification block. Has anyone else ran into this problem or know how to fix it. I have included my didRecieveLocalNotification code below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    if (notification) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        [(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController setSelectedIndex:1];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
        IMTUpdateRewardViewController *rvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"updateReward"];
        [rvc loadPushNotification:notification];
        [nav pushViewController:rvc animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into a similar problem. Eventually the culprit was a bug on my part, which was related to generating reminders to events. And if upon return from background, there were events which have already began, then a local notification was generated, and fired immediately. In short, when you encounter something like this, put a small debug printout at your UILocalNotification generating methods